# Mapping Swedish character hotkeys in MacOS to Windows 10

Tags: autohotkey

I want to map the Swedish characters å,ä,ö,Å,Ä,Ö to the MacOS hotkeys, but I want it to work under Windows 10 since at work I use a Windows machine and I do not want to keep switching back and forth from a US to Swedish keyboard layout. I think Autohotkey will be appropriate for this.

The MacOS mappings are:

- Option+a = å
- Shift+Option+a = Å
- Option + u, then a = ä
- Option + u, then shift + A = Ä
- Option + u, then o = ö
- Option + u, then shift + O = Ö

Instead of using the option key in Windows (since it doesn't exist) I will use the Left Windows key.

So far I have the script:

```
#u::
Input Key, L1
if Key=a
{
    Send, ä
}
if Key=o
{
    Send, ö
}
return

#a::
Send, å
return
```

This works for the lowercase characters but I am not sure how to implement the upper case characters.

Answer (score 1):

user3419297's answer didn't work for me but I was able to use parts of it to get the code to work properly. I have posted it below in case anyone is wondering how I was able to get it to work.

```
#u::
Input, Key, L1
if GetKeyState("LShift")
{
    if Key=a
    {
        Send, Ä
    }
    if Key=o
    {
        Send, Ö
    }
}
else
{
    if Key=a
    {
        Send, ä
    }
    if Key=o
    {
        Send, ö
    }
}
return

<#a:: Send, å

<#+a:: Send, Å
```